# Installed ubuntu now want to uninstall it

Tags: uninstall

I installed ubuntu on my laptop, there was no option to install it alongside windows 8 so i took the something else option and went to te partitioning option, and took the /sda/devca5 and then 1 tb partitiion hard drive. now my windows are not running, i cannot even refresh my windows to earlier point. how can i uninstall ubuntu

Comment: Can you run `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your question with the results?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, considering what you've said, I would try restoring the laptop to factory settings, you can use a Live USB key to find and extract any files you want to keep on the windows partition.

What kind of laptop is it?